# Image extends the container div although minimum height is set?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am having an issue with my CSS at the moment and I can't seem to figure out how to fix the issue, I tried researching this problem but I couldn't really put into words how I would describe my situation.

Basically I have set the body to 100% height so that it acts as the parent for any child attribute that may set. the main goal that I am trying to achieve is to have the background image of my `div` to fill the rest of the page without extending it and creating an scroll overflow. However instead its overflowing and extending the body height and creating an overflow, which you can see in my screenshot below:

[image]

my html code is as follows

```
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container center-nav">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MC</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
    </ul>
        </div>            

    </div>    
</nav>
<div class="main-body">
    <div class="main-wrapper">

    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS

```
html{
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100% !important;
}

body{
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100% !important;
        margin: 0;
}

.navbar.navbar-default{
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
}

.main-body{
    height: 100%;
}

.main-wrapper{
    height: 100%;
    background: url("../images/test.jpg");
    background-size:cover;
}
```

Comment: is that all of your CSS?  It looks like you're not accounting for your nav bar.  try putting `position:absolute;` on your nav bar and you should see your background shoot up a bit and the scroll bar go away.  You can also do `overflow:hidden` on your body

Comment: thank you for the suggestion although i have used overflow:hidden but im planning to add additional divs below which wont be seen if i add that i believe. Also because im using Bootstrap adding that positioning will shorten the nav bar and make it float left.

Comment: You should be able to add `width:100%` on the nav bar, then make sure it has `top:0; left:0;` as well, just to make sure.

Comment: i wish i could mark both your answers correct but yeah i think that did solve it, thank you for the answer and suggestion it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made `.main-wrapper` 100% the height of its parent. If `body` is 1000px, `.main-wrapper` will be as well. Since you also have another item in the body, it's pushing your main wrapper down.

Use `height: calc(100% - [the height of the nav])`